# Making a publicly accessible flag for a method in a class

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I'm not sure if the title makes any sense, so I'll try to describe what I would like to do:

Let's say I have a class for controlling some hardware device. The class contains a method for carrying out some procedure with the device, which involves both software and hardware operations and takes a long time. I will want to access this method in my form. However I would like to retain the possibility to cancel the procedure, enable or disable parts of it or just change some variable inside it.

If the whole procedure was in my main form then I could simply add some global flags that could be changed at any time and the operation would depend on their values. How would I go with integrating this functionality into a separate class, though?

Comment: switch to wpf and make use of MVVM pattern and data binding.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but switching to WPF isn't an option at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using the BackgroundWorker class from your form to run your routine in a separate thread and give you the ability to "Cancel" the worker thread. With regard to what parts of the process are ran within the class, you can just expose the flags on the constructor and perhaps set these when you instance the class for it to be ran under the worker class.

A more elegant solution to the enabling and disabling would be to encapsulate each part of the processing into a separate class and expose an Interface e.g. "IExecute" which exposes the specific implementation. You can then have a control class which exposes a list of each object to be processed and add to this list according to your configuration for each run.